# How does a microkernel load services?

Tags: kernel, minix

I was reading the definition of [Microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) on Wikipedia where it says:

> In computer science, a microkernel (often abbreviated as μ-kernel) is
>   the near-minimum amount of software that can provide the mechanisms
>   needed to implement an operating system (OS). These mechanisms include
>   low-level address space management, thread management, and
>   inter-process communication (IPC).

Now I'm confused. If the kernel is so minimal, then where does it get file system services to load other services?

I did go through the [MINIX3 source](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/master/minix/kernel/main.c) hoping for some answers. But without a proper line-by-line execution I'm finding it harder and harder to follow what's happening there.

Can someone please explain how microkernels know about file systems and where to find services to load? Or is my understanding of microkernels wrong and that they do actually have some basic FS support that's maybe suitable for minimal read operations?

**PS**: If this is not the right place to ask this question, could you some please suggest a place where I can ask this?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you cite has an answer if you read further, past the 1st paragraph, all the way to the end of the 2nd paragraph: *" Traditional operating system functions, such as device drivers, protocol stacks and file systems, are typically removed from the microkernel itself and are instead run in user space."*

Comment: @sawdust That sentence does not answer my question. If these functions are moved to userspace, then OS has to load and execute it. But how does OS know where to load it from without knowing where it's located on disk? Or does it mean FS is part of kernel all along, say, as an internal module loaded/executed in userspace?

Comment: Some from of filesystem always has to have a location that can be found or is known in order to bootstrap your system. The regular boot process of your OS uses a (multi stage) boot loader to load the kernel. It's depended on the system. Have a look at the Linux kernel where you can decide whenever you want to include the FS driver in your kernel or make a module. Check [this Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/what-happens-to-file-systems-during-system-boot) for an idea what might happen or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9944)